# Trim UTF8 from the end of a UTF16 string

Tags: unicode, logic, utf-16, corruption

Here's an interesting puzzle, and I'd welcome any thoughts that anyone has.  I don't think that there's a right or wrong answer here.

My program is loading a file which contains (amongst other things) string data structures.  It helpfully declares what type the structure is (UTF8, UTF16 etc), and its length (of course) before the structure, so my program knows how to handle the data.  Up to now this has worked perfectly every time.

Now I have been given a data file to load which has rubbish on the end of it - and, when I say rubbish, I mean that it looks like UTF8 at the end of a structure which is declared as UTF16.

```
D·a·v·e···E·d·m·u·n·d·s·o·n·d`upbqp!c°rÞPrpupÎÐAgâh(28.RïSÿ
```

The Dave Edmundson part is fine - it's everything after that which needs to be trimmed in this case.  The fly in the ointment is that I still need to be able to handle legitimate UTF16 extended characters (like Korean, Chinese etc).

I could just fling my hands up in the air and say, "this data is corrupt", and spit out an error.  But I'd like to be able to clean it if at all possible.  Any ideas that anyone might have would be very welcome!

This is a logical issue, hence no code - if anyone is interested, I'm using Objective-C, but all I'm really after is some intelligent conversation on how I might approach this issue.  I don't need code to be written for me!

Comment: This does not look like UTF-8 to me. Please provide a hexdump.

Comment: If it really is UTF-8, then it would be very easy to detect as UTF-8 has an easily-detectable bit pattern that is very different than UTF-16 bit pattern, so you would just have to loop through the raw bytes of the data looking for a UTF-8 bit pattern.

Comment: OK.  I've solved it by reading through the string and if the string starts out looking like its western then I trim at the point that it stops looking western.  If it doesn't start out looking western then I assume that it's non-western and use the string as is.  It's hacky - but it's the best that I can think of at the moment.